# How to solve this incompatible types in java?

Tags: java, generics

I get error in following lines.

```
error: incompatible types
required : java.util.Map.entry<java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]>
found :java.lang.Object
```

full code is below

```
package com.auth.actions;

public class SocialAuthSuccessAction extends Action {

    final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(SocialAuthSuccessAction.class);

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(final ActionMapping mapping,
            final ActionForm form, final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        AuthForm authForm = (AuthForm) form;
        SocialAuthManager manager = null;
        if (authForm.getSocialAuthManager() != null) {
            manager = authForm.getSocialAuthManager();
        }
        if (manager != null) {
            List<Contact> contactsList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            Profile profile = null;
            try {
                Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry :request.getParameterMap().entrySet() ) { // error in this line!
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    String values[] = entry.getValue();
                    paramsMap.put(key, values[0].toString()); // Only 1 value is
                }
                AuthProvider provider = manager.connect(paramsMap);

                profile = provider.getUserProfile();
                contactsList = provider.getContactList();
                if (contactsList != null && contactsList.size() > 0) {
                    for (Contact p : contactsList) {
                        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(p.getFirstName())
                                && StringUtils.isEmpty(p.getLastName())) {
                            p.setFirstName(p.getDisplayName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            request.setAttribute("profile", profile);
            request.setAttribute("contacts", contactsList);

            return mapping.findForward("success");
        }
        // if provider null
        return mapping.findForward("failure");
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: what request.getParameterMap() returns ?

Comment: That line looks OK - can you post the actual stack trace?

Comment: `getParameterMap()` is defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to cast `request.getParameterMap()`to `Map<String, String[]>`

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry :
     ((Map<String, String[]>)request.getParameterMap()).entrySet())
```

Comment: Could you explain why the cast is needed? `getParameter()` gives a `Map<String, String[]>`, so `entrySet()` gives a `Set<Entry<String, String[]>>`, which allows iterating with a `Map.Entry<String, String[]>`. Everything seems fine without casting.

Comment: You are probably working with JEE 5 and not JEE6. In JEE5, getParameterMap() is untyped meaning that you get a Map<Object,Object>. See here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
for (Object obj :request.getParameterMap().entrySet() ) {
                Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry = (Map.Entry<String, String[]>) obj;
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String values[] = entry.getValue();
                paramsMap.put(key, values[0].toString()); // Only 1 value is
            }
```

Am not really sure this will work, anyway, you got the approach. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478798/how-to-solve-this-incompatible-types-in-java/17367590#comment11996446_9478846) in the comments, `getParameterMap()` must be returning the raw type `Map` instead of `Map<String, String[]>`. This means `getParameterMap().entrySet()` returns raw `Iterable`, causing the compiler error.

If you want to avoid doing an explicit unchecked cast as the other answers suggest, an alternative is to use a variable assignment for unchecked conversion:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // getParameterMap returns raw Map
Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : params.entrySet()) {
    ...
}
```