# Error when iterating through Entry Set of HttpServletRequest Parameter Map

Tags: java, generics

Here is my source code:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> e : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
  if(e.getValue() != null && e.getValue().length > 0) { 
    someMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()[0]);
  } else {
    someMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
  }
}
```

and I get this compile error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry<String, String[]>
```

Exception is raised in the first line of the code above. The thing is this piece of code compiles and runs smoothly in Eclipse w/ Java 7; however, fails to do so in a project builder that also has the same Java version. Want to know what causes this error and how can I fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you work with the same version of the same libraries? Also, try with Oracle JDK compiler instead of ECJ. ECJ has many bugs...

Comment: May be your are compiling with the older version of the serlvet api. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29

Comment: Probably Bhesh. I am now confirming. That would explain the exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve this incompatible types in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478798/how-to-solve-this-incompatible-types-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a casting issue: you need to cast `request.getParameterMap()` to `Map<String, String[]>`

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry :
 ((Map<String, String[]>)request.getParameterMap()).entrySet()) {
    // rest of your work-arround
 }
```

Or iterate as following:

```
for(Object obj :request.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry = (Map.Entry<String, String[]>) obj;
    if(entry.getValue() != null && entry.getValue().length > 0) { 
       someMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[0]);
    } else {
       someMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's not a "casting issue", it just happens to be solved by casting.

Comment: @PaulBellora What type of issue is it? I would be interested in hearing the underlying problem.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Sure, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17367590/697449) on the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but it just got me again. I was using JEE 6 servlet API and it was working fine with Entry. After changing other seemingly unrelated things in the project I got exactly the same error. It turns out I had updated my dependencies (using IVY but that is mostly irrelevant). One of the dependencies downloaded a jar containing the JEE 5 servlet API which does not use generics. After some searching through the downloaded jars I found the offending jar (javaee-api-5.0-2.jar) and excluded it in Ivy. A quick update and all is back to normal.